# Time Complexity of Number of Islands Question

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, depth-first-search

This question has been asked several times on StackOverflow, but I ask again because it has been poorly answered or explained.

There is a question on LeetCode, link is here: [LeetCode Question Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/description/)

Where you have to find the number of islands (represented as "1"s) on a matrix.

This is my iterative depth first search (DFS) solution to the question:

```
public int numIslands(char[][] grid) {
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int counter = 0;
    int northBound = 0;
    int eastBound = grid[0].length - 1;
    int southBound = grid.length - 1;
    int westBound = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
            if (grid[i][j] == '1') {
                stack.add(i);
                stack.add(j);
                counter += 1;

                while (stack.size() > 0) {
                    int y = (int) stack.pop();
                    int x = (int) stack.pop();
                    grid[x][y] = '0';

                    if (x-1 >= northBound && grid[x-1][y] == '1') {
                        stack.push(x-1);
                        stack.push(y);
                    }

                    if (y+1 <= eastBound && grid[x][y+1] == '1') {
                        stack.push(x);
                        stack.push(y+1);
                    }

                    if (x+1 <= southBound && grid[x+1][y] == '1') {
                        stack.push(x+1);
                        stack.push(y);
                    }

                    if (y-1 >= westBound && grid[x][y-1] == '1') {
                        stack.push(x);
                        stack.push(y-1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

Most people used a recursive solution, but it seems like the general consensus is that the time complexity of a DFS solution to this question is O(m * n), where m is the number of rows and n is the number of columns in the matrix.

On the contrary, when I look at my solution, I think that the time complexity is O((m * n)^2). Firstly, we can see that the two outer for loops visit each matrix element once, so that is O(m * n). However, at each element that the two outer for loops visit, it may visit anywhere between 1 and m * n other elements, depending on the number of adjacent elements with 1s. Therefore, the composite time complexity can be `O((m*n) * (m*n))`.

What is the explanation for my complexity analysis being incorrect? Why did others ignore the complexity of the innermost while loop? Thanks

Comment: storing information about visited cells (`grid[x][y] = '0'`) drastically reduces time complexity of the algorithm: you may hit a cell either via outer `MxN` loop or via neighbour cell in inner loop, since every cell has at most 4 neighbours and you store information about visited cells (i.e. you can't hit the cell via the same neighbour twice), you hit every cell at most 6 (5 reads and 1 write) times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analysis is incorrect. It's an interesting case, because this is quite tricky, but, it really is `O(m*n)`. Let's first try to intuit what is going on without yet trying to go for a rigorous proof.

If the map is a smattering of tiny islands, you'll be 'island-filling' a lot, but each island fill operation is extremely fast: There won't be any land around your '1' at all, so you push the coords to the stack, then go through the 'pop it and scan the neighbours; any neighbouring land is added to the stack' song and dance routine which goes through only once because there is no new land to add. So, you'll be doing about `O(m*n)` landscans, but each landscan has `O(1)` performance, for a grand total of just `O(m*n)`.

If, on the other hand, the map is 1 or 2 very large islands, your 'island-fill' is far more expensive. About `O(m*n)` more expensive in the obvious case of one gigantic land (an input that is *all* 1 values). However, the amount of landscans you do here is `O(1)`, so it still adds up to only `O(m*n)`.

Perhaps you've realized the tricky part: These 2 things **are in balance** - the most middling input (as in, neither 'smattering of tiny islands' nor 'one giant island', but, a few medium size islands) has performance of `O(sqrt(m*n))` landfills to do, and each landfill's performance characteristic is, roughly speaking, also `O(sqrt(m*n))`. Multiply those together and you get back to just `O(m*n)`.

A rigorous proof of that is somewhat more difficult. This can happen with big-O notation. The trick is: The concept of worst-case scenario cannot **necessarily** be lopped up into individual pieces.

- Yes, for any given land-scan, the worst case is `O(m*n)`, sure.
- Yes, the amount of cells you need to go through and do the landscan for, worst case, is `O(m*n)`, sure.

And *usually* you can just multiply that together and be done with it. But if the worst cases are in balance (if one sub-section exhibiting worst-case **guarantees** the other ends up exhibiting best-case), then that may be an overly hasty conclusion. It then depends on how they are related: If trying to average-case them both gives you half on each, you get `O(½ m*n) *` O(½ m*n)`which is, of course, still`O((m*n)²` once you ditch the constant factors. But in this case, the 'middle' case square roots and that **is** the same 'order of magnitude', and therefore that really does mean you can't just multiply em together.

Figuring that out can indeed be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is O(mn).

You are correct that the outer loops visit each element once, so that costs O(mn).

The inner while loop is started mn times as well, and *sometimes* it may do O(mn) iterations after it starts, but how many iterations of this loop are there *in total*?  If you estimate using mn starts times O(mn) iterations, you miss an important consideration.

If you write your algorithm exactly right, then each iteration of the while loop corresponds to a 1 changing to a 0.  Since there can be at most mn 1s in the matrix, the total number of while loop iterations can be at most mn *all together*.

Because you didn't write it exactly right, you can get up to 4 stack elements when a 1 changes to a 0, but 4mn is still in O(mn), so it still works in O(mn) time.